# Overlay images in gallery with image thats being hovered over

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

searched through related topics but still can't get the answer.

I basically have a gallery with 32 images in it, when I hover over one image it only overlays it's original "box" but the rest of the 31 images is on top of the enlarged hovered image...
So I want to know how I can overlay all the images in my gallery as well as position it so that it stays in my content container and not display it outside my container.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really need a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to see what you're on about.

Comment: As @Moob points out, you don't really need to send examples through e-mail. You can use websites like JSFiddle to paste your relevant code in, save a link to it, and then post that link here for everyone else to see.

Comment: busy trying to do the fiddle thing haha...sorry new to fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C4MSz/

Answer (score 0):

try using z-index in css. Set it to a large value say 9999 to overlay above all elements on the page. Refer http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp